# kernel-devel installation using puppet throw error

Tags: puppet

I am trying to install kernel-devel on geerlingguy/centos7 vagrant box using puppet but getting error.

```
package { 'kernel-devel':
  ensure => $::kernelrelease
}
```

Throwing Error

```
==> default: Error: Could not update: Execution of '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64' returned 1: Error: Nothing to do
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What is the applicable value of `$::kernelrelease`?

Comment: Additionally, is the package available and not already installed at that version?

Answer (score 0):

This will be a problem with `ensure => $::kernelrelease`. You are asking for a version of `kernel-devel` which doesn't exist.

You can list the available versions with

```
yum list kernel-devel
```

That said, I can only see the latest version, so that `ensure` might as well be `installed`:

```
package { 'kernel-devel':
  ensure => installed,
}
```